# How to use .catch inside async-await?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I have a promise which looks like this.

```
const updateTheme = async rawTheme => {
  try {
    const existData = await Theme.findOne({ themename: rawTheme.themename });
    if (!existData) {
      return Promise.reject(Error(`Theme ${rawTheme.themename} not found.`));
    }
    Object.assign(existData, rawTheme);
    const result = await existData.save();
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
};
```

This function updates a theme in mongoDB and if it doesn't find any theme, then it returns `Promise.reject`.

I want to create a function which uses updateTheme. If it doesn't find a theme, it creates a new theme. The function is like this.

```
const updateTheme = async dbdata=> {
  try {
    let data = await dbServices.updateTheme(dbdata);
    return Promise.resolve(data);
    // Modify this function to catch an error from updateTheme and create a new theme
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
}
```

I want something like this?

```
await dbServices.updateTheme(dbdata)
  .then(
    // resolve logic
  ).catch(
    // check reject error and write create new theme logic
  )
```

But if we use async-await, any error will go directly into `try...catch` block. So my question is, how to catch the error in `.then.catch` block?

Comment: Wrap `dbServices.updateTheme(dbdata)` in a `try-catch` then `await` its result?

Comment: PS: `catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }` this makes no sense. Just don't have `catch` if all you need is just to re-throw an exception again.

Comment: @zerkms What if there's an error in `const result = await existData.save();`? Without `catch (err)`, will it be able to pass the error?

Comment: Catch + `return Promise.reject(err);` is the same as if you don't catch it at all: it would be returned as a rejected promise.

Comment: Just *don't* use `try`/`catch` if you don't want to handle the error there?

Comment: Why two `updateTheme` functions with different parameter names? i.e. what is the logic of the complete operation?

Comment: @traktor53, There's only one function `updateTheme`. The logic is to update the theme in DB, and if the theme is not present then create a new theme. So I want to catch an error coming from `updateTheme` function and in catch block I want to write a logic to create a new theme and its error handling.